# how to bind two columns of a database table up and down as a single column in data gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

how to bind two columns of a database table UP and DOWN as a single column in data gridview.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Put more effort in asking the question. It's not clear what do you want. You can put some code link etc in your question for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your response,i have to bind two columns value(eg: customerId,CustomerName)(retrieving from db) in a single column of a data Gridview

Comment: Put your code how are you binding the data into the gridview?

Comment: i dont have any codes , i just drag and dropped data grid view control there i want to bind db tables data in a single row in UP and DOWN format

Comment: [try list view instead link](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/display_data_items_and_details)

Comment: I can't understand what "UP and DOWN" is supposed to mean. Could you explain?

Comment: instead of showing two values left, right (eg CustomerIdCustomerName : 21Sankar ) i want to show these vales Up and Down 1st up and 2nd value Down in a single cell . Thank you

Comment: do you want to switch between lines, or separate the two blocks?

Comment: switch between lines

Comment: Can you modify the query? ..so you have a single block of alternating rows. Than DataBind()

Answer (score 0):

**.ASPX:**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <span>Merged cell</span>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMergedField" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") + " - " + Eval("City") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        BindData();
}

private void BindData()
{
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,City FROM Cities", con))
        {
            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                con.Open();

                var table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);

                GridView1.DataSource = table;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Merging cells in ASP.NET GridView control]